# Download file arm64-v8a Skobbler

Tags: android, skobbler-maps

I need to enable in my project processor arm64-v8a and I can not find the file libngnative.so

Comment: Why not read Official Guides? https://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android

Comment: @emandt Does the official guide tell where to find this mysterious `libngnative.so` file?

Comment: You need to download the SDK from: https://developer.skobbler.com/support#download It seems a registration (maybe payment?) is required to download it, but at this moment the Registration procedure is suspended.